# office.js - Office is not defined

Tags: html, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to use Office.js but I get the following error in my console:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Office is not defined"

I already defined office.js in my head tags like this:

```html
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
  <script src="appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.outlook.com;"> 
  <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <!-- Office JavaScript API --> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/…> 
</head>
```

but still, I got this error.

It shows this code as the error line;

```js
Office.onReady(function (info) {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    if (info.isReady) {
      initializeOutlookAddIn();
    } else {
      console.error("Office API is not fully loaded for Outlook.");
    }
  } else {
    console.error("Office API is not ready for Outlook.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post the code of your head that includes all your scripts. Do you  have the office.js placed above your own js?

Comment: not that the code you provided misses a closing `</script>` tag

Comment: i tried but it is not related to script tag.. also now I got this error; 
        
 POST https://csp.microsoft.com/report/OutlookWeb-Mail-PROD 403 (Forbidden) - do you have any other ideas ? :/

Comment: well, then you obviously have a 403 Error. You're not authorized to access the resource. The question of why is a completely different and far too broad topic.

Comment: Your code indicates that you have 2 `<script>` tags loading Office.js. You should have only one. Fix that and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @RickKirkham now i have only 1 script tag but still same

Comment: @tacoshy It currently cannot install Outlook correctly. I added the office.js file manually, but now I'm getting this error; [Report Only] This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.

Comment: like I said before, you have an authorization issue which is a too broad topic.

Comment: this is a normal issue it's mean you have not internet connection or your internet speed is slow try to refresh your add-in

Comment: so my internet speed is slow since 3 months? I dont think so @봊Јìԥ